# Translate Animation is not working perfectly in dynamic view

Tags: android, animation, dynamic, textview, translate-animation

In this project, I want to move TextView's clone from top TextView place to bottom TextView place when button is click.

I got a problem in using Translate Animation. I want to move a view to exact position(Like in Zapya).

In Zapya, when user select item and choose "send", the **gridview item's clone** move to user icon.
So, I use Translate Animation to move view. And I created a view dynamically to show item's clone.

Using Translate Animation works with view that is initially created in xml but not with view that is dynamically created.

The code is here

```
    top = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewtop);
    bottom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewbottom);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int []from = new int[2];
            int []to = new int[2];

              from[0] = (int) top.getX();
            from[1] = (int) top.getY();
             to[0] = (int) bottom.getX();
            to[1] = (int) bottom.getY();
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) top.getParent();

            view = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            view.setWidth(top.getWidth());
            view.setHeight(top.getHeight());
            view.setX(from[0]);
            view.setY(from[1]);
            view.setText(top.getText());
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            view.setId(0x23454657);
            vg.addView(view);


            TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( 0, 0 , from[1], to[1] );
            anim.setDuration(1000);
            anim.setFillAfter( true );
            view.startAnimation(anim);



        }
    });
```

and xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewtop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />


    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Move"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewbottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

"view" show only starting and ending time. But not in between. How can I solve that.
Please tell if there's any other way. I will thanks a ton.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the duration Time, may be that is a problem

```
anim.setDuration(4000);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I had already tried that. It didn't work. :(